# Quick tabs module change title to bottom

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I am facing a problem. I have a module called QuickTabs, new to Drupal and confused.

I like to change the position of the title of the quicktabs, instead of top and I would like my buttons or links to be on the bottom. I worked the css but it seems that the render is on the inc.

```
    tile1 title2
---------------------------
    content content
```

Change to:

```
     content content
---------------------------
     title1  title2
```

Any hints of how I can do this? I am using Drupal 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to start by downloading the excellent [devel_themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module from Drupal.org and install it on your site. It will also require that you install the devel module.

Once you install it and enable it, devel_themer will tell you what template (*.tpl.php) is being used. You can then go to that template and alter the order of the HTML elements directly. You will also find devel_themer to be a great tool for learning Drupal theming.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your template.php file from your (custom) theme:

```
function trasys_qt_quicktabs(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $output = '<div '. drupal_attributes($element['#options']['attributes']) .'>';

    $output .= drupal_render($element['container']);

    $output .= drupal_render($element['tabs']);

  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: trasys is the your theme name

Comment: indeed, I'm sorry :)